# Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I've got a game where if you hit an enemy, you go to the gameover screen. I added a view controller to main.storyboard and made the class GameOver. However, it says I need an entry point and when I load the app it is just a blank screen. The thing is, I dont really need an entry point because I am switching scenes in the code when an enemy collides with the player. No button "entry point" needed. How can this be fixed?

[image]

[image]

Here is the code for collision with enemy:

```
func CollisionWithEnemy(Enemy: SKShapeNode, Player: SKSpriteNode) {

    //Highscore
    var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()


    if (Score > Highscore) {
        var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        HighscoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Highscore")
    }

    var gameOver:SKScene = GameOver(size: self.size)
    ScoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    Enemy.removeFromParent()
    Player.removeFromParent()
    self.view?.presentScene(gameOver, transition: transition)


}
```

Comment: You should award one of the answers - Sumit's helped me.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[image]

Set a text for your storyboard ID

Comment: Can this be anything I want?

Comment: yes particularly you set the storyboard ID to be used when you are pushing/presenting code without segue

Comment: This only worked for me after I cleared Derived Data and restarted XCode.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set one of your ViewControllers as the initial view controller for your storyboard.

[image: init view controller option]

**EDIT**

You need a segue to your GameOver scene. Right now there's no way for your initial view controller to present it.

Comment: It looks like there's no segue to your GameOver scene, so there's no way for your initial view controller to present it.

Comment: Ok so I don't need a segue if I'm just switching scenes through code? Because it worked fine switching to the gameover scene when I was doing it through code. I'll add a segue once I get home.

Comment: As you saw, Xcode will yell at you if you don't have a segue, even though your program works the way you want. You could move GameOver to it's own nib if you want to present it yourself and not have the storyboard manage it.

Comment: Ok thanks so much for the help I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @Darkstar How are you switching scenes through code? The error also says that your view controller does not have a storyboard identifier with which to create it in code.

Comment: self.view?.presentScene(gameOver, transition: transition)

Answer (score 1):

Error reason is the presence of the same viewController identifier! You need to give different viewController above storyBoard different identifier.
[image]